# Shell custom autocomplete - not to list previous listed arguments

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete, sh

I have programmed auto completion to my script but when I enter TAB is is showing the previous filled arguments also. how to avoid this.

here is my code:

```
_load_opt ()   
{                
  COMPREPLY=()   
  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  local prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}

  case "$prev" in
   "--create")
       COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "--name --type --size" -- $cur ) )  
       return 0 
       ;;
  "--delete")
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "--name" -- $cur ) )
        return 0 
       ;;
 esac

 if [[ ${cur} == -* ]]
 then
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "--create --delete" -- $cur ) )
 return 0
fi
}

complete -F _load_opt ./run.sh `
```

i sourced this script.
and when i run

```
# ./run.sh --create --name file.txt --
--create  --delete
```

Because of the last default `if` statement it is auto completing the main arguments. But I want to auto complete `--type --size` and NOT `--name` again.

I tried to add one more case with `--create --name`.But I should go add with all combinations. That doesn't sounds correct.

How can I achieve this?. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want, you'll need to examine the entire command line, one option at a time, something like this (not tested much): (**Edit:** *uses associative arrays, for which you need bash v4*)

```
_load_opt () {
    # If we're at the beginning, only allow the verb options.
    if (( COMP_CWORD == 1 )); then
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "--create --delete" -- "$2"));
    fi;
    if (( COMP_CWORD <= 1 )); then
        return;
    fi;

    # Otherwise, construct the list of allowed options based on the verb
    local -A flags;
    case ${COMP_WORDS[1]} in 
        --create)
            flags[--name]=ok;
            flags[--type]=ok;
            flags[--size]=ok
        ;;
        --delete)
            flags[--name]=ok
        ;;
        *)
            return 0
        ;;
    esac;

    # And scan the entire command line, even after the current point, for already
    # provided options, removing them from the list
    local word;
    for word in "${COMP_WORDS[@]:2}";
    do
        unset flags[$word];
    done;

    # Finally, complete either an option or an option value, depending on the
    # previous word (always the third argument to this function)
    # The first three lines in the case statement are just examples
    case $3 in
        --name) COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "valid name list" -- "$2")) ;;
        --type) COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "good bad ugly" -- "$2")) ;;
        --size) COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "small medium large" -- "$2")) ;; 
        *) COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${!flags[*]}" -- "$2")) ;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. though there were syntax error I could able to correct it. thanks.

Comment: @Dinesh: bash doesn't report any syntax errors on my system. There was one place where it would have been better to have quoted the expansion, which I changed. What syntax errors are you seeing?

Comment: `-A` flag to that local variable was not allowed in my Linux machine. so i made it array using `-a` option. And I think may be because of that `flags[--name]=ok;` was failing.  And `${!flags[*]}` was printing indexes instead of values because of `!` sign.

Comment: @Dinesh: Ah, you don't have bash v4, so you don't have associative arrays. All those syntaxes are part of associative array support. You can do a similar thing without associative arrays (and maybe you have already), but it would be more complicated.